# React Native Images - require vs import

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

React Native has a mechanism to automatically bundle and serve images corresponding to device's screen density using @2x and @3x suffixes.

See: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

The docs mention a `require` syntax, but I was wondering if this also works for `import` syntax? I can't find any information on this and can't find a way to test this.

```js
// this automatically serves @1x, @2x, @3x
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// this as well?
import icon from './my-icon.png';
<Image source={icon} />
```

Comment: the second one throws an error right?

Comment: No it does not throw an error, but I can't tell if it also looks at the `@2x` and `@3x` variants or just uses the `@1x` image.

Comment: :O not sure, with this import type

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the implementation of how React Native resolves assets: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js#L38

Whenever you're passing the `source` prop to an `<Image />` component it will just lookup the import path on the filesystem and use that to resolve other density images. Since a path can be determined from both a CommonJS (`require(…)`) import and an ES Module `import` statement they will act the same for React Native's asset resolution.

If you really wanted to verify you could use a tool like Flipper, Proxyman or mitmproxy to inspect Metro's network traffic and verify that your @2x or @3x device is resolving to something like `http://localhost:8081/assets/image@2x.png`

Answer (score 0):

I tested it by using different images for the `@2x` and `@3x` variants and they work exactly the same!

[image]